# Defining Correlation for Groups of Random Variables?

Tags: probability

**Part 1:** Consider the Multivariate Normal Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). Suppose we have some random variables $X_1, X_2, ... X_N$ that have a joint Multivariate Normal Distribution:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
X_2 \\
\vdots \\
X_n
\end{bmatrix}
\sim \text{MNV}(\mu, \Sigma)$$

where:

- $\mu$ is the mean vector, and
- $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix.

We can expand this as follows:

- Mean vector $\mu$:

$$
\mu = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2 \\
\vdots \\
\mu_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

- Covariance matrix $\Sigma$:

$$\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} & \cdots & \sigma_{1n} \\
\sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22} & \cdots & \sigma_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\sigma_{n1} & \sigma_{n2} & \cdots & \sigma_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$

In the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, the diagonal elements $\sigma_{ii}$ are the variances of the individual random variables $X_i$, and the off-diagonal elements $\sigma_{ij}$ are the covariances between $X_i$ and $X_j$. The matrix is symmetric, meaning $\sigma_{ij} = \sigma_{ji}$.

**Part 2:** Now, consider Correlation in the above context

The correlation coefficient $\rho_{ij}$ between $X_i$ and $X_j$ is given by:

$$\rho_{ij} = \frac{\sigma_{ij}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{ii} \cdot \sigma_{jj}}}$$

where:

- $\sigma_{ij}$ is the covariance between $X_i$ and $X_j$,
- $\sigma_{ii}$ is the variance of $X_i$, and
- $\sigma_{jj}$ is the variance of $X_j$.

**My Question:** It seems that in the above case, we are fundamentally limited to only defining Correlation between 2 variables - we can never define Correlation between 3 variables.

**Is it possible to infer correlation indirectly?**

For example, suppose there are 3 variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$. If:

- $\rho_{1,2} = \rho_a$
- $\rho_{1,3} = \rho_b$
- $\rho_{2,3} = \rho_b$
- **Can we make any statements about the 'Correlation' of all 3 variables together,** e.g. $\rho_{1,2,3}$?
- If there $X_1, X_2 ... X_N$ random variables and we know the pairwise correlation between each pair $\rho_{i,j}$ : can we infer the correlation between "groups" (groups of minimum size = 3) of random variables?
- And finally, is it possible to *a priori* define pairwise correlations between all pairs of random variables such that the correlation between "groups" (groups of minimum size = 3) of random variables are equal to a certain amount?

Thanks!

**Notes:**

- I am aware of something called Copulas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) that can be used to define the Joint Probability Distribution for random variables having different underlying probability distributions - but I am not sure if this concept can be applied here.

Comment: When the probability distribution is gaussian, higher order correlations are directly obtained from the variances and covariances. Maybe this might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem

Comment: @userrandrand: thank you for your reply! I will check this out!

Comment: my apologies, I looked quickly at your post, it seems your question might be more general. Maybe you're asking how to define a normalized correlation between 3 variables regardless of the distribution of the random variables? I am not sure, maybe $E[X_i X_j X_k]/(E[X_{i}^3] E[X_{j}^3] E[X_{k}^3])^{1/3}$ but that is just a guess.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I wonder if this question is even possible?

Comment: what question ?